# create path string from path components

Tags: sql, sqlite, recursion

Consider the following table containing information about a directory structure:

```
CREATE TABLE t (id INTEGER, name TEXT, parent INTEGER);
INSERT into t VALUES
(1, "", 1),
(2, "a", 1),
(3, "b", 2),
(4, "c", 3),
(5, "d", 1);

SELECT * FROM t;
```

[image]

From this table it should be possible to obtain a column containing the path names

```
""
"a"
"a/b"
"a/b/c"
"d"
```

It would seem that some kind of recursion is necessary.  So far I have only managed to create a text column of parent directories:

```
SELECT b.id, b.name name, b.parent parent, a.name as parent_name
FROM t a INNER JOIN t b ON a.id = b.parent;
```

[image]

How to proceed from here?

Comment: Beware: you can not assume your rowid is immutable!

Comment: @LS_ᴅᴇᴠ good point, I've changed the example so that rowid isn't used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you must use recursion, which in SQLite may be accomplished using `WITH`:

```
WITH RECURSIVE tf AS (
   SELECT id, name, parent, name AS full, parent AS p FROM t
UNION
    SELECT id, name, parent,
        (SELECT name FROM t WHERE id=tf.p) || "\" || full,
        (SELECT parent FROM t WHERE id=tf.p)
        FROM tf WHERE p IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT id, name, full FROM tf WHERE p IS NULL;
```

Comment: I can't get this to work, it keeps going on without ever returning.

Comment: Yes, becaus of `(1, "", 1)`. This should be `(1, "", NULL)`.

Comment: I.e., root node should have no parent (instead of being parent of himself!)